# Запятая перед словом "типа"

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли ставить запятую перед словом "типа":

1. Мы говорили о рискованных операциях(,) типа вытаскивания мелочи из карманов.
2. С нами ехали друзья и просто приятели(,) типа Кати Ивановой и Женьки Петрова.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) Два варианта, обособление зависит от логического ударения:** Мы говорили о **рискОванных** операциях,  типа вытаскивания мелочи из карманов (пояснение). Мы говорили о рискованных операциях типа вытаскивания мелочи из карманов (определение).

**2)** С нами ехали друзья и просто приятели, **типа Кати Ивановой и Женьки Петрова** (обособление оборота со значением  дополнительного пояснения).

**О выражении "типа"**

Слово "типа" имеет значением "наподобие, вроде", например:  Птица вроде (наподобие, типа) воробья.

**Обособление  оборотов  с предлогом НАПОДОБИЕ, как известно, является  факультативным,** например: Анна Фёдоровна, Катя и Леночка стояли в дверях **наподобие** живой картины, ожидая визга, вопля, битых чашек. [Людмила Улицкая. (1995-2000)]. Мне давно хотелось написать о Коле. Что-то **наподобие** воспоминаний.[Сергей Довлатов(1986)]. Вместо стола там стойка, **наподобие бара**, в холле остались все, кто не пошёл купаться, они сидели в креслах, пили кофе, трепались, ожидая нас. [Д. А. Гранин. Месяц вверх ногами (1966)]

**Соответственно, обороты  со словом "типа" также обособляются факультативно** в зависимости от значения: определение или дополнительное пояснение. Надо отметить, что подобные обороты характерны **для  разговорного стиля речи.**

Кроме того, слово "типа" в последнее время приобрело значение **"сленговой частицы"** со свободной позицией в предложении: Типа не надо нам втирать про природу, романтику и свежий воздух! [Запись LiveJournal (2004)]

Answer (score 1):

В контексте обоих предложений  можно усмотреть не просто сужение обозначенного перед этим более широкого понятия (говорили об операциях типа вытаскивания - здесь не нужна запятая), а пояснительное уточнение - что значит "рискованных" или "просто приятели"; "типа" неформальным образом заменяет здесь слова "таких как" (например, вроде), перед которыми запятая **нужна**.